# CanCan, Devise and the "current_user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid, cancan

I have a simple setup with Cancan and Devise.

I wanna show the edit button only to "Admins" and Users which owns the "location":

So in the show.html.erb I have

```
<% if can? :manage, location, :user_id == current_user.id %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_path %>
<% end %>
```

My ability.rb looks like this

```
if user.roles.include?('User')
  can [:show, :index, :create], Location
  can :manage, Location, :user_id => user.id
end
```

The locationController contains this on the very top:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

User Id is referenced in Location.user_id

**But it does not show up the EDIT Button...**

Did I miss something?

**PS: user.id does not work in the view. and current_user.id does not work in the ability.rb**

PPS: My roles are stored in an array eg: Roles ["User", "Admin"] and works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working with

```
can :manage, Location, :user_id => user.id.to_s
```

I hope it helps someone!